# Experience in/ with / no preposition. Do we have to use a preposition after "Experience"?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

She doesn't have any experience loving someone.

She doesn't have any experience **with** loving someone.

She doesn't have any experience **in** loving someone.

Are all the above sentences grammatically correct?
What's the difference in their meaning?
Is it necessary to use a preposition after the word "Experience" .

Comment: When in doubt, leave it out (if it makes sense that way). "She doesn't have any experience loving someone." is fine.

Comment: If you had to use one of the sentences given above, which one would you choose?

Comment: The first one..

Comment: According to NGram, there is a significant difference in usage of "have experience X" where X is a preposition, between BrE (of >> in > with) and Ame (in > with >> of).  For "have experience x love",  it's of >> in > with for both BrE and AmE. The numbers for this query are very low, though, and zero for  "have experience x loving".

Answer (score 4):

I think to answer this question, we need to distinguish between two different senses of *experience*. I quote from LDOCE:

1. [U] *knowledge or skill that you gain from doing a job or activity, or the process of doing this. It's about knowledge or skills*

In this sense we can use of/in/with after experience to make noun phrases or gerund as in

> You’ve got a lot of experience of lecturing.
>
> my experience in many areas of the music business

*in* is often followed by a gerund. However noun phrases are also possible. *'Experience in'* implies the person has been (professionally) ***trained*** in something (a special field of activity) as in

> We need someone who has experience in ​marketing and ​teaching,

and  after *'of'*, we mainly use gerund unless the word 'experience' is preceded by *get/gain* as in

> The programme enables pupils to gain some experience of the world of work.

And afer *with* we tend to use noun phrases (persons/animals) and it implies that the knowledge has been gained about something by ***actual physical*** contact as in

> I have experience with children.

Let's say this is said by a sister who raised his brother while his mom was always away working.

2. *[C] something that happens to you or something you do, especially when this has an effect on what you feel or think. It's about what happens.*

In this sense we use of/with/for (***Not*** in) after experience to make noun phrases as in

> This was my first experience of living with other people.

In this sense, I think you can use both *with* and *of* interchangeably to make the same meaning as in

> It was her first experience of/with dealing with people from another culture.

I assume you try to refer to *loving someone* simply as *an event, or type of event, lived through which does not have the idea of gained knowledge.* So, I think sentence **two** is the safest choice here. About number **one** (experience doing something) I found **no** reference to back it up so I think it's better to be avoided at least when formality matters. Many think of it as acceptable though as in

> She has a great deal of experience (in) introducing new products to international markets.

Comment: I would take out the preposition in most of the examples above. "Experience in designing widgets" can (and should) be shortened to "experience designing widgets".

Comment: I can see no compelling reason to drop the 'in', Eric.