# “experience in” VS "experience with"

Tags: prepositions

> 1. A has many years of experience **in** material design and production technology.
> 2. A has many years of experience **with** material design and production technology

I have seen both 'with' and 'in' followed by 'experience". If I want to convery the meaning a company or a person has worked in the areas of material design and production technology for many years and is experienced, which preposition should I choose?

.

Comment: You may find this helpful: [Experience in/ with / no preposition. Do we have to use a preposition after “Experience”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85691/experience-in-with-no-preposition-do-we-have-to-use-a-preposition-after-exp)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Think of the example of a farmer. He works IN a field WITH a plough.

Most areas of work are likewise referred to as "fields". So when you are speaking about your "field" of work, you would say you have experience *in* it.

However, *both* can be very useful when writing a CV/resume or a job application. For example, let's say that you were applying for a job in the field of ICT and you wanted to demonstrate your experience. If you had already worked in that field or similar, you would want to detail that. But maybe you have worked in an unrelated field (say, general administration) and that role contained an element of ICT that gave you relevant experience. You couldn't legitimately claim you had worked *in* ICT but you could show that you have some transferrable skills by detailing the things you worked *with*.

For example:

> I have 3 years' experience working **in** an ICT technical role.

or

> I have 3 year's experience working **with** computers.

Comment: If the farmer has that much experience, he's probably outstanding in his field.
  (sorry, please excuse the pun. It was too irresistable)

Comment: @Spudley I would think that a farmer with a lot of experience would be standing *in* their field.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, **in** could be used when you are referring to a topic or a field of study, e.g. "experience in web design, experience in robotics". and **with** sounds more natural for me if used with a tool or concrete technology, e.g. "Experience with CCS, javascript, Experience with sensors".

Summarizing, I think **in** could be used when the experience was gained by being exposed or being involved in a field, while **with** could be used for experience gained by using something.

This is what I understand as a non-native English speaker.

Answer (score 7):

- Experience **in** software development.

  (ie the field you have experience in)
- Experience **with** Java, Spring and Netbeans.

  (ie the specific tools, products, etc that you've used while gaining that experience)

There is a fairly clear distinction in most cases.  But that said, the distinction is also subtle enough that it is likely to go unnoticed if you get it wrong.

Comment: It's not always that clear, though: _experience **in** translating_ OR _experience **with** translating_. I think either are ok, unless you are a certified translator in which case only the former would be ok, I think. The meaning is subtly differently. Likewise, if you say _experience **with** software development_, you're saying you did it once or twice, but it is not your trade per se.

Answer (score -1):

According to the Oxford Collocations Dictionary For Students of English, the preposition you use for the noun "experience" is "of": PREP.~ of/ "She has considerable professional experience of translation."

https://books.google.com.mx/books?id=tt3uoAEACAAJ&dq=Oxford+Collocations+Dictionary+For+Students+of+English&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y

Comment: That seems incorrect to me. Can you please quote the section of that book which states that "of" is **the** correct preposition, to the exclusion of "in" and "with"?

Comment: Look for the word experience as a noun in that book

Comment: I never said the book excluded in or with, am just telling what I found in the book and those were not there.

Comment: It's correct to say that "of" the only preposition that dictionary says collocates with "experience", but it doesn't say it's "**the**" preposition, meaning the *only* preposition, as you've worded it.